# Failed to parse package.json data,package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying my collection with newman module run tester, with *newman run https://XXXXXX* , it works properly, but if I put the URL in the package.json in the "test" and do *npm test*, it doesn't work, what is happening?
The URL is an http://getpostman...

```
"scripts": {
  "start":"index.js"
  "test": "https://XXXXXX"
}
```

Comment: I think it’s just a syntax error in the package.json, may be it’s the missing comma after “index.js” ?

Comment: now after writing the comma when i do npm test , the output is: https://www.getpostman..: not found , but if i do newman run https://www.getpostman.. it works

Comment: Yeah, because it’s expecting a module name and not a link! You need to add ur test script name instead of that XXXXXX link.